# Infinite/Circular UI Scrollview Syncing Issues

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have an issue that I've been struggling with how to solve, I have an infinite/circular UIScrollview/header (Part A, in the image below), that I want to sync up with a UIViewController (part B). When the header scrolls, I want to calculate the percentage that it scrolled and apply that to the lower controller.

I already know how to do this, however the problem is that in order to make the scrollview infinite, I used the Apple street scroller example. Since i'm using the contentOffset in the trying to calculate the percentage scrolled, when the method (recenterIfNecessary) below is called, it causes the content offset to jump and mess up the calculation (i.e. It will calculate 50% and then jump back to 10% or some other value when the method is called).

I've done a lot of searching on SO to see if someone else had a similar issue and I couldn't find it, there are posts about how to implement infinite/circular behavior (which I have working), however I couldn't find anything specific to my problem. I also checked controls created on Cocoa Controls and I couldn't find one like this either. Essentially what I am trying to achieve is something like the Windows Pivot Control: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gdUb5kYUXOQ

```
- (void)recenterIfNecessary {
    CGPoint currentOffset = self.contentOffset;
    CGFloat contentWidth = self.contentSize.width;
    CGFloat centerOffsetX = (contentWidth - self.bounds.size.width) / 2.0;
    CGFloat distanceFromCenter = fabs(currentOffset.x - centerOffsetX);

    if (distanceFromCenter > (contentWidth / 4.0)) {
        self.contentOffset = CGPointMake(centerOffsetX, currentOffset.y);

        for (UIView *label in self.visibleLabelTitles) {
            CGPoint center = [self.labelContainerView convertPoint:label.center toView:self];
            center.x += (centerOffsetX - currentOffset.x);
            label.center = [self convertPoint:center toView:self.labelContainerView];
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Funny... Someone else posted about this topic at about the same time as you did, but they're implementing a UIPageViewController: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23629347/how-to-make-uipageviewcontroller-go-in-circles . I would definitely recommend using a UIPageViewController combined with a UIScrollview for your situation as well since it will automatically detect the content offset and recenter the view.

Comment: I don't think a UIPageViewController will give me the same feel, also that doesn't solve my original problem with calculating the scrollview percentage due to the recentering method.

Comment: You want it to look like the video right? That's just like UIPageViewController in combination with UIScrollView. And in doing UIPageViewController with UIScrollView, the reentering happens automatically... I'll try to post a video in a bit to show you what I mean...

Comment: Here's what I'm talking about -- http://s149.photobucket.com/user/lyndsey_s/media/scroller.mp4.html

Comment: Yes that is it, do u know where that video is from? Is there a sample project to reference?

Comment: That's a program I made this morning as an example using UIPageViewController and UIScrollview controller just as I'd suggested. It's a video I took of my own program.

Comment: Basically, I used one UIPageViewController and 2 UIScrollViews... If you scroll one UIScrollView, once that scroll view has ended dragging, set the content offset of the other to match (so there's a slight delay).

Comment: Would u be willing to share the program?

Comment: Yeah, but honestly, I hacked it together really quickly on the day that you asked your question... I can post some code a little later though.